# how can i make uipickerview with multiple row selection and displaying liste options selected in uitextfield iphone?

Tags: iphone

i have to make a picker view with multiple row selection. i have tried this solution but i was failed for me.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {


        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width - 20, 44)];
        cell.tag = row ;
        UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                               initWithTarget:self
                                                               action:@selector(toggleSelection:)];
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
    }
    if ([self.selectedItems indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row]] != NSNotFound) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.options objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;

}

 -(void)toggleSelection:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:recognizer.view.tag];
    NSUInteger index = [self.selectedItems indexOfObject:row];

    if (index != NSNotFound) {

        [self.selectedItems removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    } else {

        [self.selectedItems addObject:row];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are doing in viewForRow method?

Answer (score 2):

For multiple row selection in pickerView you can use https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALPickerView

Answer (score 1):

for mutliple selection we have to create custom picker by using Tableview.[once see this one](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/alpickerview)